# how to create a SSIS package which creates three text files, using same variables but the textfile is only created when the correct data is found?

Tags: ssis

There are only 3 files that can be created : "File_1", "File_2" and "File_3". The same variable name is used in each instance (User::FileDirectory) and (User::File_name), but because the actual value of the variable changes, a new file is created.However the files are only created if there is data to go into the file. i.e. if there are no records to populate the file, it will not be created at all. When the files are created, the date the file was created should also be added to the filename. eg: File1_22102011.txt

Ok if the above was a little confusing, the following is how it works,

All the files use the same variable, but it is reset before each file is created.

• So it populates a result set in memory with the first sql selection (ID number, First_Name and Main_Name). It sets the file variable to “File_1”. If there are records in the result set, it creates and writes to this filename.

• Then it creates a new result set with the second selection(Contract No). It sets the variable to "File_2". If there are records in this new result set, a new file will be created from the variable(which now has a new value)

• Finally a third result set is created (Contract_no, ExperianNo, Entity_ID_Number, First_Name, Main_Name), and the file variable is set to "File_3". Again if there are records in the result set, then this file will be created and written to.

I have worked on a few methods to achieve this but they all have failed, So little help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which part exactly do You want us to help You with? What did You try? What parts of described logic have You solved?

Comment: I have done the part where it populates File_1 the first point. I did this by creating a script task which sets the file name, the a file system task and then a data pump that will populate the data in the flat file. I would like to know how I can do the rest? I'm new to SSIS, so I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track here, so I would like your perspective on this. The file does get populated with the data specified in Point 1 but with the wrong date. Actually It would be great if you could tell me how you would approach the whole situation above. Thanks

Comment: I thought over your question over and over and I couldn't find a better (easier to maintain) solution than the one billinkc suggested. Another approach: create three files and then iterate over files in that folder and check their sizes and delete empty ones with File system task. You can easily find help for these tasks on the Internet and to get file properties check: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/03/get-file-properties-with-ssis.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While what you have works, I think it'd be rather painful to maintain.

I would approach it as 3 sequence containers running in parallel. Each container would have a data flow and two file tasks hanging off it based on success of the parent and the value of row count variable. If the row count variable is 0, delete the file. If it's greater than 0, rename it to File_n

As you can see, I have a container for the first file. The data flow creates an output a.txt file. Based on the value of the variable @RowCount1, it will either delete the empty file or rename it to File_1.

[image: Control flow pattern]

Each data flow would look like a source query, a row count transformation and a file destination with a temporary name (a.txt, b.txt, c.txt). As a file is always created, even if it's empty, we will need to delete or rename it afterwards which will be accomplished based on the file operation tasks.

In my opinion, this approach will be cleaner as it will allow you to test and debug each item in a cleaner manner rather than dealing with an in-memory dataset.

Comment: Thanks alot. Your method is simple and does exactly what it should do. I just added a Script task to add the date to the filename instead of a file task to rename the file because I wanted it to be File1_21102011.txt. Thanks once again. :)

Comment: Oh just another query, I'm new to SSIS, so I want to know how did you create the file within the Data Flow Task? Did you use a Derived coloumn?

Comment: Create a connection manager, probably a flat file (delimited, fixed width, or ragged right) and that defines the layout of the file. In the Data flow, the source operation is most likely an OLE DB source with your query as the source. Add any transformations you need to that. The terminus of the flow would be a Flat File Destination. Wire the flow into that, mapping columns as appropriate. In your case, it may be easier to just connect the destination to the Data Flow and then create a new CM based on the existing meta data.